# Why are the requirement for imgur hosted images being enforced this year? (2017 Community Promotion Ads)

Tags: feature-request, imgur, community-promotion-ads

In the past, despite being listed as a requirement, it's been possible to use images hosted outside of imgur.
This allowed for all sorts of neat [dynamic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9467/64390) [imagery](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1016/599).

However, this year, any such plans of trickery were swiftly squashed:

[image]

I'd like to request that this requirement be relaxed, or at least that the reason for its sudden enforcement be made clear.

Comment: Now, not even the dynamically created image showing the number of active bounties works, because it is served from a different server. I liked that very much.

Answer (score 6):

The requirement is only enforced on the *initial* edit (the ads still work, [e.g. here](http:////meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/7187/5763)); so a work-around I use is to add *some* image when creating the answer and then edit the answer immediately and *remove the image*.